# How to access a packages methods?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm developing a laravel package, inside the package I have a repository that deals with the data.

When a user installs the package, how can I get them to interact with the repository in their app?

Should I set up a facade so they can do something like:

```
SuperPackage::getSomeData();
```

Or should I use a different way?

The docs state:

> When building a third-party package that interacts with Laravel, it's
>   better to inject Laravel contracts instead of using facades. Since
>   packages are built outside of Laravel itself, you will not have access
>   to Laravel's facade testing helpers.

I presume this is just meant for internals of the package, calling the package externally, facades are still ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you pretty much need to write a Service Provider to get your package integrated into a user's application anyway, I think you should make your package available by dependency injection using contracts. I don't think it hurts to provide a facade for convenience as well, since really it's only one extra file that references something in your service provider.

**Your contract:**

```
namespace Your\Package;

public interface YourPackageContract
{
    public function availableMethod();
}
```

**Your implementation:**

```
namespace Your\Package;

class YourPackage implements YourContract
{
    public function availableMethod()
    {
        //  Implement your method
    }
}
```

**Your service provider:**

```
namespace Your\Package;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class YourPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // Tell Laravel that when an instance of YourPackageContract is requested, an instance of YourPackage should be returned
        $this->app->singleton('Your\Package\YourPackageContract', function($app) {
            return new YourPackage();
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['Your\Package\YourPackageContract'];
    }
}
```

**Your Facade:**

```
namespace Your\Package\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class YourPackage extends Facade
{
    public function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'Your\Package\YourPackageContract';
    }
}
```

**Usage in a controller:**

```
class SomeController
{
    public function index(YourPackageContract $yourPackage)
    {
        // $yourPackage should now be an instance of YourPackage
        $yourPackage->availableMethod();

        // You can also use the Facade which refers to the same instance
        YourPackage::availableMethod();
    }
}
```

You could always use the `->alias()` method in your service provider if you want to create multiple ways of accessing your class, with more readable names etc.

Note: I've just written this directly here, I haven't had the chance to test it.

Comment: Thanks, how would a user access a method in a repository via dependency injection? Would they have to inject the Repository Class? Or can they just use the package name? Could you show me a rough example? I'm concerned if it's the repository class then this relies on the user knowing the repositories name whereas a facade just seems easier.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, I haven't tested anything though.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, so I would need to reference the repositories interface for dependency injection. I have a further question, assume that I have perhaps 10 repositories dealing with various parts of data that from the package. For dependency injection i presume I just inject the repository I want, how would this work with a facade? Would I need multiple facades, one for each repository? Or is there another way?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? I'm afraid it's quite difficult to answer without much context.

Comment: Say I had a table for users, posts, products, reviews etc. I also had a repository dealing with data for each, so a users repo, posts repo etc. I want the user to be able to access these repos from a facade, - how? More than one facade? Another way?

Comment: In that case, I would use a single Service Provider, a single Facade and a single implementation with methods that you can use to get instances of the repositories. You could make a `userRepository` method available in your contract/implementation that returns an instance of your user repository for example. Then you could use dependency injection OR your facade to access it: `YourPackage::userRepository()->methodOnUserRepository()`. How does that sound?

Comment: Yeah thats sounds like an ok way to go about it, MyPackage::user->all();

Comment: If you take Socialite for example, it lets you use multiple providers by doing something like `Socialite->with($provider)->redirect()` where `$provider` could be any of the available implementations,

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)